# Preserve content type of a blob while copying from one container to another

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to copy a blob from one container:

```
blob_url = blob_service.make_blob_url(source_container, source_blob, sas_token)
blob_service.copy_blob(target_container, target_blob, blob_url)
```

This is happening alright, however the content type of the `source_blob` is application/pdf, and the content type of `target_container` is being set as : `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Within the Blob storage UI, I can click on the properties of this blob and change the content type, however, how do I do that within the Azure Python SDK?

Comment: This should not be happening. A copy blob operation preserves the properties of the source blob. So the content type of target blob should be same as that of source blob.

Comment: I know, this is weird. Maybe as Ivan Young mentioned in their answer, it's a version problem? I could use the `set_blob_properties` workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `set_blob_properties` method:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContentSettings

accountName="xxx"
accountKey="xxxx"

services = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName,account_key=accountKey)

#set the content_type to whatever you need
settings = ContentSettings(content_type='application/pdf')

services.set_blob_properties(container_name,blob_name,content_settings=settings)
```

By the way, I use the python sdk `azure-storage-blob==1.4.0`, and when use `copy_blob` method, the content-type is also copied as "application/pdf"